# Unit testing the Auth Component

Tags: cakephp, authentication, testing

I am using the following code to test the login action in UsersController

```
public function testLogin() {
    $data = array('User' => array(
                'username' => 'hello',
                'password' => '411'
                    )
            );
    $this->Users = $this->generate('Users',array('components'=> array('Auth','Session')));
    $this->Users->Auth->staticExpects($this->once())
                        ->method('user')
                        ->with('id');
    $this->testAction('/users/login', array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'post'));

}
```

and the fixture is-

```
class UserFixture extends CakeTestFixture {
    public $import = array('model' => 'User', 'records' => true, 'connection' => 'fixture');
}
```

adn action is-

```
public function login() {

        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            if($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                return false;
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Wrong Username Or Password,Please Try Again'));
            }
        }
    }
```

It always showing

> Expectation failed for method name is equal to  when invoked 1 time(s).
>   Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

What is the problem?Cant find any solution,and the reason also.Please help.

Comment: i think the problem is in somewhere else...i am looking for this..

Comment: login is failing in the above code..how to solve this problem.?

Comment: Normally you wouldn't bother unit testing the auth component, because the CakePHP core dev's already do that, so you don't have to. Your unit tests should focus on the unique functionality of your app - not the Cake core.

Comment: its ok. but if i have to check this in any condition then how to do this?the mocking is working perfectly but the login process is failing evrytime,it is always returning false from the else condition.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you need but I'll paste some example code in an answer that should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.it worked.

```
public function testLogin() {
    $data = array('User' => array(
            'username' => 'sasa',
            'password' => '111'
            )
        );
    $this->Users = $this->generate('Users', array());
    $result = $this->testAction('/users/login', array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'post'));

    $this->assertEquals($data['User']['username'],$this->Users->Session->read('Auth.User.username'));
    $result = $this->testAction('/users/logout');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem mocking the auth component is that in addition to including `auth` in your components array, you need to specify which methods of Auth to mock, and how to mock them.

The way I deal with AuthComponent in my tests is I create a superclass with a method: `_generateMockWithAuthUserId` which mocks the Auth component, among other things, the way I need.

I've pasted the code from my superclass below.

```
class AppControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->User = ClassRegistry::init('User');
    }

    public function tearDown() {
        unset($this->User);
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function testPlaceholder(){
        // This just here so we don't get "Failed - no tests found in class AppControllerTest"
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    protected function _generateMockWithAuthUserId($contollerName, $UserId){
        $this->authUserId = $UserId;
        $this->authUser = $this->User->findById($this->authUserId);
        $this->controller = $this->generate($contollerName, array(
            'methods' => array(
                '_tryRememberMeLogin',
                '_checkSignUpProgress'
            ),
            'components' => array(
                'Auth' => array(
                    'user',
                    'loggedIn',
                ),
                'Security' => array(
                    '_validateCsrf',
                ),
                'Session',
            )
        ));

        $this->controller->Auth
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method('loggedIn')
            ->will($this->returnValue(true));

        $this->controller->Auth
            ->staticExpects($this->any())
            ->method('user')
            ->will($this->returnCallback(array($this, 'authUserCallback')));

    }

    public function authUserCallback($param){
        if(empty($param)){
            return $this->authUser['User'];
        } else {
            return $this->authUser['User'][$param];
        }
    }
}
```

And then here's a example of a class that inherits from that superclass. Take note of where/how it calls `_generateMockWithAuthUserId`. Basically, doing that sets up a suitable controller with Auth mocked for the appropriate user id.

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . DS . 'AppControllerTest.php';

class EmployeeNotesControllerTestCase extends AppControllerTest {

    public $fixtures = array(
        // your fixtures go here
    );

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->EmployeeNote = ClassRegistry::init('EmployeeNote');
    }

    public function tearDown() {
        unset($this->EmployeeNote);
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function testSupervisorIndexCanNotSeeNotesOnSelf() {
        $authUserId = 1;
        $this->_generateMockWithAuthUserId('EmployeeNotes', $authUserId);

        $this->controller->Session
                ->expects($this->once())
                ->method('setFlash');

        $result = $this->testAction('supervisor/employee_notes/index/'.$authUserId, array('return' => 'vars', 'method' => 'get'));

        $this->assertTrue(empty($result['employeeNotes']));
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i am facing --Argument 1 passed to AuthComponent::identify() must be an instance of CakeRequest, null given...what should be the problem behind this?